# Can the estimation of parameters in EM be decreases and increases during the estimation process

Tags: expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution

I am working on EM algorithm (manually implemented in R). I saw that the estimation of the parameters vary from iteration to another. That is, it decreases at some iteration and then start increasing at other iteration. However, the log likelihood increases at all iteration till converges. Is that acceptable in EM algorithm? or I may have a problem with my R code?